# можно ли писать чисто на .NET Сore без ASP?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

В общем надо создать десктоп программу под Linux, работая при этом на Windows.

на .NET Core до этого не удавалось поработать и вот вопрос, можно ли как то писать приложение на Core как на framework а не ASP.NET Core который как я понял под веб сделан.

и если да то как? потому что в visual studio у меня только проекты под ASP.NET

Comment: Попробуйте запустить установщик студии и там потыкать "галочки". А вообще, веб-проект от обычного отличается подключенным Sdk в файле проекта, просто уберите Web и оставьте Microsoft.NET.Sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно.

Сразу оговорка терминологии: `.NET Core` устарел, в данный момент `.NET`

#### КАК

Установите сам `dotnet` [здесь](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

Далее двигайтесь по документации и выбирайте, что вам больше подходит. По ссылке, которую я привел, вы можете выйти на документацию по тому продукту, который вас интересует